# Why reference in pointer array doesn't have data?

Tags: c++, c++17

I am learning C++ and I have a problem that I'm trying to solve.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <cstring>

class Page
{
    private: int page_id;
    int pin_count;
    char data[10];

    public:

        Page()
        {
            page_id = 0;
            pin_count = 0;
        }

    Page(int p_id)
    {
        page_id = p_id;
    }

    void IncPin()
    {
        pin_count += 1;
    }

    char *GetData()
    {
        return data;
    }

    void operator=(Page *p)
        {
            page_id = p->page_id;
            pin_count = p->pin_count;

            std: memcpy(data, p->data, 10);
        }

        ~Page() {}
};

class BufferPool
{
    private: Page * pages;
    public:

        BufferPool()
        {
            pages = new Page[2];
        }

    Page* NewPage(int index)
    {
        Page *page = new Page(1);
        page->IncPin();
        pages[index] = page;
        return page;
    }

    void FetchPage(int index)
    {
        std::cout << pages[index].GetData() << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    BufferPool buffer_pool;
    Page *page = buffer_pool.NewPage(0);
    std::memcpy(page->GetData(), "aebclkfhti", 10);
    buffer_pool.FetchPage(0);

}
```

When I debug in the 'main', I see after this line is run
`std::memcpy(page->GetData(), "aebclkfhti", 10);` that "page"'s "data" indeed has the string "aebclkfhti".

But when this line is called `buffer_pool.FetchPage(0);` an empty string is printed. I expect it to print "aebclkfhti"

It's a requirement to use `data` as a character array.

What I can do to correct this situation? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `"aebclkfhti"` is 11 characters in total. Don't miss the terminator. And use `std::string` for strings

Comment: using `std::string` is no contradictin to "use a character array". `std::string` is a character array and more.

Comment: fwiw, c-arrays, `new` and raw pointers, and `memcpy`, is not beginners c++ but advanced c++

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried to add the null terminator but still nothing is displayed when `buffer_pool.FetchPage(0)` is called.

Comment: the thing is that your code is so *advanced* that I also cannot spot the issue. Others may. I didnt say that missing null terminator was the only issue, but it had to be fixed. You need a terminator in `char data[10];` otherwise printing is undefined behavior due to running over the end of the array

Comment: I'm also getting: `main.cpp:42:13: warning: label 'std' defined but not used [-Wunused-label]  std: memcpy(data, p->data, 10);`

Comment: *I am learning C++...* In my opinion, the use of C arrays, `malloc` (and `free`), `new` (and `delete`), `new[]` (and `delete[]`) are all advanced C++ topics only suitable to learn after programming in C++ for over year.  Instead use smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr` and containers like `std::vector` and `std::string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've written data to the `Page` pointed to by main's `page`, which is a different object to `buffer_pool.pages[0]`.

This is the minimum change to have those point to the same object:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <cstring>

class Page
{
    private: int page_id;
    int pin_count;
    char data[10];

    public:

        Page()
        {
            page_id = 0;
            pin_count = 0;
        }

    Page(int p_id)
    {
        page_id = p_id;
    }

    void IncPin()
    {
        pin_count += 1;
    }

    char *GetData()
    {
        return data;
    }
    
        ~Page() {}
};

class BufferPool
{
    private: Page ** pages;
    public:

        BufferPool()
        {
            pages = new Page*[2];
        }

    Page* NewPage(int index)
    {
        Page *page = new Page(1);
        page->IncPin();
        pages[index] = page;
        return page;
    }

    void FetchPage(int index)
    {
        std::cout.write(pages[index]->GetData(), 10);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    BufferPool buffer_pool;
    Page *page = buffer_pool.NewPage(0);
    std::memcpy(page->GetData(), "aebclkfhti", 10);
    buffer_pool.FetchPage(0);

}
```

N.b. you can write a character array without a null terminator to a `std::ostream`, using the member `write`.

It looks like you wrote an `operator=` to silence an error that should have given you pause.

Comment: Hi Caleth, many thanks. Indeed your solution works. Is there a way to make it work with `Pointer *pages` as Buffer Pool's private instance variable? 

Do you've a good recommendation to understand pointers?

Comment: Also, curious, if there is a way to visualise this? Should one use GDB to help visualise all this ?

Any other tools any one can recommend? Thanks again for all help.

Comment: @Waqas I'd recommend having a `std::vector<Page> pages;` instead. As it stands `BufferPool`'s members work at cross purposes to each other.

Comment: @Waqas the first thing you need to learn about raw pointers is that you (almost) never need them. They do have uses, but they are not as common as the usual poor c++ teaching wants you to believe